# Run MongoDB in a Docker container with no volumes

Tags: mongodb, testing, docker, continuous-integration

This is a slitty odd question but I would like to run a mongo DB with no volume at all.

The reason is, so I can run tests on the CI and be able to clear everything down after the tests run.

We are building the image from the [Docker Mongo dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/5fa47142887600edcd437e7689f40342b3572e71/3.0/Dockerfile#L65) and removing the volume (line 63) `VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb` but at the end of the `docker build` it errors with `write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob872455794: no space left on device`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Could not reproduce. Tested with Docker 17.03 on Ubuntu 16.04, 1GB RAM image on DigitalOcean. Removed `VOLUME` line, built the container, started the container, and connected to port 27017.

Answer (score 0):

mongo needs a data volume to write data to when it runs.

i think best option is to remove the volume when you remove the container

`docker rm -v my-mongo`

adding the `-v` flag to `docker rm` will remove associated volumes

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/

Comment: Alex Blex - that information is outdated. Docker on Windows and OSX don't use VirtualBox anymore. plus, i never said anything about host mounted volumes. data volumes are not the same thing.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I misunderstood the question then. Good to learn there's no need for vm anymore.